# Generate functions without closures in python

Tags: python, function, closures, pickle

right now I'm using closures to generate functions like in this simplified example:

```
def constant_function(constant):
    def dummyfunction(t):
        return constant
    return dummyfunction
```

These generated functions are then passed to the init-method of a custom class which stores them as instance attributes. The disadvantage is that that makes the class-instances unpickleable. So I'm wondering if there is a way to create function generators avoiding closures.

Comment: Callable classes could be an option, though they come with their own set of caveats and complexities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a callable class:

```
class ConstantFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, constant):
        self.constant = constant
    def __call__(self, t):
        return self.constant

def constant_function(constant):
    return ConstantFunction(constant)
```

The closure state of your function is then transferred to an instance attribute instead.

Comment: In Python 3.3, pickling a lambda gives me `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed`. (Pickling regular functions with a name works, but only references the name and module of that function.)

Comment: @delnan: hrmz, anonymous lambdas need to be loadable like functions, it appears. Removed the option for now.

Comment: @delnan: It turns out I misread [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878300/serializing-and-deserializing-lambdas) and thus thought lambdas would work. :-)

Comment: Thank you for that information! I haven't heard about callable classes until now..

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'd recommend this for general use… but there's an alternate approach of compiling and `exec`'ing the code.  It's generating a function w/o a closure.

```
>>> def doit(constant): 
...   constant = "def constant(t):\n  return %s" % constant
...   return compile(constant, '<string>', 'exec')
... 
>>> exec doit(1)
>>> constant(4)
1
>>> constant
```

Note that to do this inside an enclosing function or class (i.e. not in the global namespace) you have to also pass in the appropriate namespace to `exec`.  See: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement

There's also the double `lambda` approach, which is not *really* a closure, well, sort of…

```
>>> f = lambda x: lambda y:x
>>> g = f(1)
>>> g(4)
1
>>> import dill
>>> _g = dill.dumps(g)
>>> g_ = dill.loads(_g) 
>>> g_(5)
1
```

You seemed worried about the ability to pickle closure-like objects, so you can see even the double lambdas are pickleable if you use `dill`.  The same for class instances.